# how do you multiple variables in multiple methods?

Tags: java, variables

> I have a class (MarkCollection) that basically gets the marks from a user in one method (getMarks), then it gets the average of those marks in another method (getAverage) and lastly it needs to get the grade of the average mark in the 3rd method (getGrades).

Everything works perfectly until i get to the getGrades method.  What i need to know is how do i get the 'average' variable (which stores the average of the marks) into the getGrades method. The getGrades method needs to take the 'average' variable and put it through an IF statement to get whatever grade the student will get based on the average.

In short, how do i get the variable 'average' (with the same value stored inside of it as in the getAverage method) into the getGrades method to work out the average correctly?

```
class MarkCollection extends Main {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int length = 3;

int[] marks = new int[length];

public  void getMarks(){


for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++) {
System.out.println("enter mark number "  + (counter + 1));
marks[counter] = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
}     

input.close();
}     

public void getAverage(){

     int sum = 0;

            for(int i=0; i < marks.length ; i++)
                    sum = sum + marks[i];

            //calculate average value
            double average = sum / marks.length;

            System.out.println("Students Mark average is : " + average);

   }
```

> Everything works fine until this method. The program doesnt recognize the 'average' variable. How do i get this method to recognize the average variable as it does in the previous method, with the same value stored inside of it.

```
    public void getGrade(){


    double grade;

    if (average >= 90) {
        grade = 1.1;
    } else if (average >= 70 ) {
        grade = 2.1;
    } else if (average >= 50 ) {
        grade = 2.2;
    } else if (average >= 70 ) {
        grade = 2.1;
    } else if (average < 50 ) {
        grade = 3.0;

    System.out.println("The Students Grade is = " + grade);
    }  
   }
  }
```

Comment: is the getGrade method and the getAverage method located in same class ?

Comment: have `getAverage()` return a double so its signature becomes `public double getAverage()`, then change `getGrade()` to take an average as an argument so its signature becomes `getGrade(double average)`

Comment: i will try that now kevin, yes ahmed it is in the same class

Comment: @JasonOsborn Do not vandalize your question. That's not acceptable behavior here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getGrade() method needs to accept a double as a parameter, and your getAverage() method needs to return the average as a double. Then in your either your getMarks() or main method, you need to call your getGrade() method. It would look something like this.

```
public void getMarks(){
    ...
    getGrade(getAverage());
} 

public double getAverage(){
    double average = 0;
    ...
    return average
}

public void getGrade(double average){
    ...
}
```

Here are the official javadocs on passing arguments:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: thanks, but the only problem i have no is that in the main method (where i call all the methods), every methods gets called perfectly and works, except for the getGrades method. the program doesnt recognize it and tells me to "create getGrades method". Ive used : getGrade(getAverage());

Comment: Where is your main method? Do you need to create a new object? If that's the case, it may not be appropriate to pass in an argument to getGrade(). You could try the following:


MarkCollection markCollection = new MarkCollection();
markCollection.getGrade(markCollection.getAverage());

Comment: My main method is in another class. Mine now looks like this : class3.getGrade(class3.getAverage());......but it still doesnt pick up 'getAverage'

Comment: No problem glad to help. If you want to upvote and accept the answer too that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

First, change your `getAverage` method to return type `double`, and then `return average` inside of it:

```
public void getAverage(){
    ...
    //Dividing two ints results in a truncated int value! Cast one to double.
    double average = ((double)sum) / marks.length; 
    System.out.println("Students Mark average is : " + average);
    return average;
}
```

Then, call the method inside your other method (instead of wherever you're calling it from already):

```
public void getGrade(){

    double grade; 
    double average = getAverage();
    if...
```

Or, if you want to still call `getAverage` from your main method, you can pass the average as a parameter instead:

```
public void getGrade(double average){

    double grade;
    if...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare average as a field instead of a local variable.

```
class MarkCollection {
    double average = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = 3;

    int[] marks = new int[length];

    public void getMarks() {

        for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++) {
            System.out.println("enter mark number " + (counter + 1));
            marks[counter] = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        }

        input.close();
    }

    public void getAverage() {

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + marks[i];
        }

        //calculate average value
        average = sum / marks.length;

        System.out.println("Students Mark average is : " + average);

    }

    public void getGrade() {

        double grade;

        if (average >= 90) {
            grade = 1.1;
        } else if (average >= 70) {
            grade = 2.1;
        } else if (average >= 50) {
            grade = 2.2;
        } else if (average >= 70) {
            grade = 2.1;
        } else if (average < 50) {
            grade = 3.0;

            System.out.println("The Students Grade is = " + grade);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make the getaverage() return double  average  like that :

```
       public double getAverage(){

           double average=....;

           return average;
        }

        public void getGrade(){

        double average=getAverage();
        }
```

or define the average as a global variable in the class

```
        public double average =0;

        public void getAverage(){
        this.average=...;
        }



        public void getGrade(){
         this.average..
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are encountering is that average is only in the scope of `getAverage()`. Only the method `getAverage()` can access double average. One way to solve this problem is to have `getAverage()` return a `double`, and call that method from inside of `getGrade()`

```
public double getAverage(){
    // Same code here
    return average;
}

public void getGrade(){
    double average = getAverage();
    double grade;
    // If statements here
}
```